# Weird screen in dual boot (windows-ubuntu) when booting into windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'm using a Lenovo g50 laptop and I have installed windows 10 alongside with Ubuntu 16.04.

I know that this has been asked before:
[Weird screen starting Windows from dual-boot setup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637387/weird-screen-starting-windows-from-dual-boot-setup)

I tried setting nomodeset in grub following these instructions:
[How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

But I can still see it...
Is there another way to make this go away?

I don't know if it helps, these are the contents of etc/default/grub:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: Did you update your `/etc/default/grub` file with `nomodeset` and then run `sudo update-grub` afterwards?

Comment: Yes, I already did, it didn't work...

Comment: sorry that's my only thought. I don't dual boot anymore and when I used to I never had that problem. Can you `edit` your question to include your computer make and model? It might help others solve your problem quickly.